# Spring stomp - send a message from server using SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket, stomp

I am trying to send a message using stomp from server to a client. I know that using sock.js and stomp on client side I can send a message from one user to another, without much server-side interaction, simply by using a @SendTo annotation in a controller method. However, the message that I want the user to receive is generated on the server (actually, I'm sending a whole object, but for simplicity's sake, let's just say I'm trying to send a String). Specifically, this deals with friend request acceptance, and when one user accepts a friend request, the one who sent the request should receive a message that his request was accepted. So, after a simple ajax call to a rest controller method for accepting a request, the method should also send the message to the other user. Here's the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserController{
    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate simp;

    @RequestMapping(value="/acceptFriendRequest/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public boolean acceptFriendRequest(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        UserDTO user = getUser(); // gets logged in user
        if (user == null)
            return false;
        ... // Accept friend request, write in database, etc.
        String username = ... // gets the username from a service, works fine
        simp.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification", "Some processed text!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's the web socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/sendNotification").withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

        config.enableSimpleBroker("/notify");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/project_sjs");
    }


}
```

And this is the javascript function:

```
function setupWebsockets(){
    var socketClient = new SockJS("/project_sjs/sendNotification");
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socketClient);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame){
        stompClient.subscribe("/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification", function(retVal){
            console.log(retVal);
        });
    });
}
```

When a user accepts the friend request, everything is written fine in the database. I can even see that the other user is my friend now when I refresh the page. However, the other user never receives the message that his request was accepted. 
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did u get the answer?

Comment: I solved this problem with a different approach. Instead of subscribing all users to the same endpoint "/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification", and then differentiating them by username, I ended up subscribing each user to a different endpoint, for example "/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification/John123". This way, everyone with the username John123 (which is only one person, because usernames are unique) will get the notification. And it worked well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with a different approach. Instead of subscribing all users to the same endpoint "/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification", and then differentiating them by username, I ended up subscribing each user to a different endpoint, for example "/project_sjs/notify/acceptNotification/John123". This way, everyone with the username John123 (which is only one person, because usernames are unique) will get the notification. And it worked well enough.

Comment: Do you have a github link to this project? Cheers